# How to render a component without rendering AppComponent at all times?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to render 2 components (**AppComponent** and **UserComponent**) without having to render AppComponent at all times. Here's what my code looks like:

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AppComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user', component: UserComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
 I'm in the app component
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now for some reason "I'm in the app component" text is rendered 2 times as you can see in the picture:

[image]

Now when I go to route '/user' I see this:

[image]

so my question is How can I only see **"I'm in the app component"** text when on on '/' route and
when I'm on '/user' route only see **"user works!"**? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppComponent renders by default as its the root component. You would need to  create another component and use that as your home component. Please check the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nivcaf?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz demo? Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with stackblitz

Comment: you live demo still renders "I'm in the app component" when accessing /hello route. I just want to render Hello Works! text when accessing "/hello" route

Comment: I have further updated my answer. You need to use little different approach and create a new home component.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is: Don't. Make an OtherComponent, then remove all but the `<router-outlet>` tag from AppComponent.html.

Treat that AppComponent as the top level that everything flows through. Angular is very opinionated, and if you do things in a way that's not standard practice, Angular will act like it's meant to.

If the two branches should really be that separate, consider having separate apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because default route `''` matches both `''` and `'user'` paths. Try setting `pathMatch: 'full'` to the `AppComponent` and it shouldn't render on other routes:

```
  {
    path: '', 
    component: AppComponent
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

But more of an issue here is that the default route should be a separate component and your `AppComponent` should be the one that holds the `router-outlet`.